# Как убрать лишнюю колонку в Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть код:

```
import os
import glob
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
os.chdir("C:/")

def populate_tree(tree, node):

    path = tree.set(node, "fullpath")
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children(node))

    parent = tree.parent(node)
    special_dirs = [] if parent else glob.glob('.') + glob.glob('..')

    for p in special_dirs + os.listdir(path):
        ptype = None
        p = os.path.join(path, p).replace('\\', '/')
        if os.path.isdir(p): ptype = "directory"
        elif os.path.isfile(p): ptype = "file"

        fname = os.path.split(p)[1]    
        id = tree.insert(node, "end", text=fname, values=[p, ptype])

        if ptype == 'directory':
            if fname not in ('.', '..'):
                tree.insert(id, 0, text="dummy")
                tree.item(id, text=fname)


def populate_roots(tree):
    dir = os.path.abspath('.').replace('\\', '/')
    node = tree.insert('', 'end', text=dir, values=[dir, "directory"])
    populate_tree(tree, node)

def update_tree(event):
    
    tree = event.widget
    try:
        
        populate_tree(tree, tree.focus())
    except:
        pass

def change_dir(event):
    tree = event.widget
    node = tree.focus()
    if tree.parent(node):
        try:
            path = os.path.abspath(tree.set(node, "fullpath"))
            print(path)
            file=open(path,"r")
            ri=file.read()
            label.delete(1.0, END)
            label.insert(1.0, ri)
            file.close()
        except:
            pass

root = Tk()

vsb = Scrollbar(orient="vertical")
hsb = Scrollbar(orient="horizontal")

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("fullpath"))

vsb['command'] = tree.yview
hsb['command'] = tree.xview

tree.heading("#0", text="Directory Structure", anchor='w')
label=Text(root,font=("Ubuntu",2))
populate_roots(tree)
tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', update_tree)
tree.bind('<Double-Button-1>', change_dir)
hsb.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)

tree.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)

vsb.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
label.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)

root.mainloop()
```

Результат:

[image: результат]

И мне нужно убрать выделенную красным цветом колонку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно при создании дерева указать параметр `displaycolumns=()` (с пустым списком или пустым кортежом), тогда дополнительные колонки кроме колонки дерева отображаться не будут:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("fullpath"), displaycolumns=())
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

```
tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вместо скрытия колонки делать ее нулевой ширины - это костыль